# how to join after left join complex mysql queries

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have this query

```
SELECT 
       currency_code, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'buy'THEN to_amount END ) AS BUY, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'sell' THEN to_amount END ) AS SELL, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'sell' THEN rate END ) AS SELL_RATE, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'buy' THEN rate END ) AS BUY_RATE, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'buy' THEN rate END ) AS AVG_BUY_RATE, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'sell' THEN rate END ) AS AVG_SELL_RATE
FROM tb_currency
LEFT JOIN tb_bill 
   ON tb_currency.CURRENCY_ID = tb_bill.CURRENCY_ID
     AND tb_bill.TYPE  IN ('buy', 'sell')
     AND date( DATE_TIME ) >= '2011-01-01'
     AND date( DATE_TIME ) <= '2011-01-11'
GROUP BY currency_code
```

that will output this:

[image]

Right now i want to join this query with another table called **tb_user**

the tb_user have PK called **user_id** and the **tb_bill** that is use in the query above also have foreign key called **user_id**

**tb_user**

```
user_id (pk)| user_name | branch_id
```

**tb_bill**

```
bill_id (pk) | user_id (fk)|
```

**Desired result should be the above picture plus one column branch_id.
If it doesnt have branch_id, return null.**

I tried several times but still cant join it correctly. Hope you guys can help.

Thanks.

Comment: mana kau punya schema ? where is the schema for tb_user ? and also, please indent your sql, code indentation is important too

Comment: What is the desired result? You want to `GROUP BY currency_code, user_id`? or you want to pivot on userid or what?

Comment: sorry guys i updated the question.

Comment: but there might be multiple `user_id` s and hence multiple `branch_id` s for a given `currency_code`. Which do you want to show? Even if you know there will only be one you'll still need to put it in an aggregate or add it to the `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three conditions in the join (the AND clauses) might be giving you trouble. Those three conditions are selection criteria, not join criteria.

Also, your use of CASE looks odd to me. I'm sure it works, but IF might be better suited for a one-condition function. In the below, if the fields are floating point rather than integer then replace the 0 with 0.0.

```
SELECT currency_code, 
    SUM(IF(TYPE = 'buy', to_amount, 0)) AS BUY,
    SUM(IF(TYPE = 'sell', to_amount, 0)) AS SELL, 
    SUM(IF(TYPE = 'sell', rate, 0)) AS SELL_RATE,
    SUM(IF(TYPE = 'buy', rate, 0)) AS BUY_RATE,
    AVG(IF(TYPE = 'buy', rate, 0)) AS AVG_BUY_RATE,
    AVG(IF(TYPE = 'sell', rate, 0)) AS AVG_SELL_RATE,
    tb_user.whatever_field,
    tb_user.whatever_other_field
FROM tb_currency
    LEFT JOIN tb_bill ON tb_currency.CURRENCY_ID = tb_bill.CURRENCY_ID
    LEFT JOIN tb_user ON tb_bill.user_id = tb_user.user_id
WHERE tb_bill.TYPE IN ('buy', 'sell')
    AND date( DATE_TIME ) >= '2011-01-01'
    AND date( DATE_TIME ) <= '2011-01-11'
GROUP BY currency_code, tb_user.user_id
```

Finally, all-cap field names look odd to my eye as well. Whatever works for you though.

Comment: The use of `CASE` might look odd to you but it's standard SQL and looks less odd to me!

Comment: No worries. We each have our own eye for coding aesthetics. I'm sure my code is abhorrent to some and elegant to others. :-) The `IF` works in MySQL, but if CASE is standard and portable, then all the better.

Answer (score 1):

add user_id to SELECT part
after

```
LEFT JOIN tb_bill ON tb_currency.CURRENCY_ID = tb_bill.CURRENCY_ID
```

place

```
LEFT JOIN tb_user ON tb_user.id = tb_bill.user_id
```

also you missing WHERE ( put instead first AND )
and

```
GROUP BY currency_code, user_id
```